# Cannot get PubNub EON chart to work

Tags: pubnub, particles, photon

I have run into a dead end trying to get the following HTML to work. I am trying to use the real time gauge chart to display a value coming from a photon. This is the snippet code from the pubnub site.

(I have proven that the published value is arriving in the Javascript using the commented out pubnub code in the Javascript. The value is displayed in the P tag.)

The P tag is displayed on the screen, but no gauge is displayed.

Could you please have a look at my code and guide me on where I have made a mistake. I have not worked with EON before, so I may be making very basic mistake.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.16.1.min.js"></script>  -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="//pubnub.github.io/eon/v/eon/0.0.10/eon.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//pubnub.github.io/eon/v/eon/0.0.10/eon.css"/>


<div id="chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
*var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({subscribe_key:  'xxxxxxx'});

/*
  pubnub.subscribe ({channel : "datatest", message : function(tempmsg)
            {document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = tempmsg.eon.data;}});

*/

var channel 'datatest';
eon.chart({
            channel: channel,
            generate: {
                        bindto: '#chart',
                        data: {
                                type: 'gauge',
                                },
                        gauge: {
                                min: 0,
                                max: 100
                                },
                        color: {
                                pattern: ['#FF0000', '#F6C600', '#60B044'],
                                threshold: {
                                                values: [30, 60, 90]
                                            }
                                }
                        }
            });
</script>



<body>
    <p id ="x"> This is my text that will be replaced by the value from the photon </p>
</body>

</html>
```

The output from the photon looks like this:

```
publishing message: {"eon": {"data":56}}
publishing message: {"eon": {"data":56}}
publishing message: {"eon": {"data":56}}
publishing message: {"eon": {"data":56}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing line of code in the PubNub EON JavaScript embed code for the Gauge Chart.

You must add `pubnub: pubnub,` to bind the graph instance to the PubNub stream.

Comment: The landing page has the omission but all github repo examples include it. We have filed a docs bug to update the landing page.

Comment: The page with the omission has been updated. Thanks again for reporting this.